# DNA alignment, optimizing recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, bioinformatics

So i have a  function `get_best`, that finds the best score for 2 DNA strands.
summary of the code:

```
def get_best(pointer_1, dna_1, Pointer_2, dna_2):
     if len(dna_1) == pointer_1 or len(dna_2) == pointer_2:
         score = check_score(dna_1, dna_2)
         return score dna_1, dna_2
    return max(get_best(no_gaps, advance pointers), 
               get_best(gap in first, advance only first pointer), 
               get_best(gap in second, advance only second pointer)
```

This not real code, it's just the idea, it works, but is real slow for big strands. i need it to be recursive, so any ideas on how optimize it? or maybe some other ways to make it recursive code so that it works faster?

Comment: Why recursion? In most cases (in Python at least, don't know about other languages) iteration is faster.

Comment: Home work, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is about efficient implementation algorithm which is essentially the same as [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) algorithm.
As in the wikipedia link, you should store the intermediate results somewhere. Your code code computes the same results again and again and again. It is really inefficient.

Here is an observation why your code is inefficient.
Suppose we would like to compute the value of function `g` which is recursively defined by `g(i,j) = F(g(i-1,j),g(i,j-1),g(i-1,j-1)` where `F` is any predefined function.

Let us follow the code when we evaluate at (2,2).
The code recursively evaluate the following points:

```
g(2,2) -> g(1,2), g(2,1), g(1,1).
```

Then to evaluate at (1,2), further recursion is invoked:

```
g(1,2) -> g(0,2), g(1,1), g(0,1)
```

Also for (2,1)

```
g(2,1) -> g(1,2), g(1,1), g(1,0)
```

The two recursion chain, starting from (1,2) and (2,1), evaluate the same point, (1,1), separately. Thus g(1,1) is computed more than once. This is obviously inefficient. We can store the result of g(1,1) to avoid duplicated computation.